# MVC3 not rendering my SelectList when using @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to render a ViewModel using Razor and MVC3.  For some reason my SelectList (WidgetTypes below) does not render even though the rest all render just fine.  Can anyone shed some light as to why not?  I do not want to change the View to use @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SystemName) etc. for each field because I use dynamic models for the widgets which will cause the same problem.

My ViewModel:

```
public class CreateWidgetViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The System Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "System Name")]
    public string SystemName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Widget Type")]
    public string WidgetType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Widget Types")]
    public SelectList WidgetTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var widgetTypes = from wt in _widgetService.WidgetTypes
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = wt.WidgetName,
                          WidgetType = wt.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
                      };

    var viewModel = new CreateWidgetViewModel
    {
        WidgetTypes = new SelectList(widgetTypes, "WidgetType", "Name")
    };

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

My View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = "widgets";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />&nbsp;or&nbsp;@Ajax.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index", "Widget", 
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "ajax-replace" })
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Using SelectList in your model is not a good thing because it is not serializable - if you ever turn on state server, you're toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Html.DropdownListFor` helper if you want to generate a drop down list. The fact that you have used `SelectList` as type to some of your properties doesn't mean that the default editor template will render a `<select>` box. So you will have to write a custom editor template.

You may take a look at the following [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) to see how those default templates are implemented.

Comment: I have now done that.  Not happy with it this way but it will just have to be, thanks.